# Autofac and enums with HasFlag

Tags: c#, wcf, enums, autofac

I use the following interface in my logic layer to enforce single responsibility (can be broken but you have to jump through hoops and give yourself a severe headache to achieve that).

```
public interface ILogic<in TContext, out TOutput>
{
    #region Execute

    TOutput Execute(TContext context);

    #endregion
}
```

Lets assume with have the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompanyRequest : ExtensibleDataObject
{
    #region Properties

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public CompanyOptions Options { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

and

```
[DataContract]
public class CompanyResponse : ExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    // TODO: Store any errors occurred for graceful handling

    //..

    //..
}
```

The Company DataContract will contain the data requested via the CompanyOptions enum, eventually there will be 30 - 50 such properties.

I realise that its not possible for Aufofac to inject a list of only the logic instances needed at construction but I do know via IIndex it is possible for the Company operation contract or other name (up for debate right now) can get the IIndex stored during construction and with either through Metadata or otherwise it can for instance do a Where(registration => context.Flags.HasFlag(logic.Metadata.Flag) leaving a list of the logic implementations responsible for satisfying the call. (My explanation is probably wrong and full of holes)

My question is which is the preferred method of handing this type of behavour.  Ideally I'd avoid metadata completely as I'm part of a team whose job it is to introduce a custom nuget server through which we review and control which packages teams are allowed to use so it would be kinda of ironic for me to keep start adding new packages such as the Aufofac.Extras.Metadata package.

Logic registration is automatic/opt-in via an attribute:

```
[Logic(Entity.Uk, CompanyDetail.PaymentTrends)]
public class PaymentTrends : ILogic<CompanyRequest, NullLogicResponse>
{
    public NullLogicResponse Execute(CompanyRequest request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Each assemblies which registers with Autofac does so via a module like so:

```
public class LogicAutofacModule : Module
{
    #region Load

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once IteratorMethodResultIsIgnored
        builder.RegisterTypesWithAttribute<LogicAttribute>(typeof(ILogic<,>));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules<DataAutofacModule>();
    }

    #endregion Load
}
```

Where RegiserTypesWithAttribute looks like this:

```
public static class ContainerBuilderRegisterTypesWithAttribute
{
    #region RegisterTypesWithAttribute

    public static IEnumerable<IRegistrationBuilder<object, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>> RegisterTypesWithAttribute<TAttribute>(this ContainerBuilder builder, Type typeBeingRegistered) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var assembly = typeof(TAttribute).Assembly;

        // ReSharper disable once LoopCanBeConvertedToQuery ... no thanks!
        foreach (var type in assembly
                        .GetTypes()
                        .Where(type => type.HasCustomAttribute<TAttribute>()))
        {
            var registration = builder.RegisterType(type)
                   .As(type.GetInterfaces()
                   .First(i =>
                          i.IsGenericType &&
                          i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeBeingRegistered));

            yield return registration;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I can't yet get my head area around the best way to register the type and its metadata.  The LogicAttribute exposes a Metadata property consisting of the Entity and Flag.  Keyed can I guess be excluded as its only for strings? so do I go with IIndex<> and then ensure my constructor's parameter looks similar to this:

```
public LogicDispatcher(IEnumerable>Lazy<Meta<LogicMetadata, ILogic<NullLogicResponse, CompanyRequest>>> logicEnumerable)
{
    _logicEnumerable = logicEnumerable;
}
```

and then within its Execute method:

```
public NullLogicResponse Execute(CompanyRequest request)
{
    var applicableLogic = 
        _logicEnumerable.Where(metadata => metadata.HasFlag(request.Flag);

     foreach (var logic in applicableLogic)
     {
         logic.Execute(request)
     }
}
```

Any help on improving the above and/or a better way to deal with that problem at hand would be gratefully appreciated.  Thank you.

P.S.

There would be 30 and growing ILogic interfaces with the same types.  Each would would/could be fired via the TPL for instance so I'm happy to receive X number of registrations at once.

Comment: Guys have I worded this too poorly for you to grasp the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've handled this for now is as follows.  I'm not particularly happy with it but it working.  The reason I'm not happy is that its not particularly AutoFac-ish.

I added the following extension method to enumerate all types in the assembly which have the required attribute.  When a type is found an Action is called allowing the developer to do whatever he wants registration wise:

```
public static class ContainerBuilderEnumerateAttributedTypes
{
    #region Properties

    public static void EnumerateAttributedTypes<TAttribute>(this ContainerBuilder builder,
        Action<Type, TAttribute> action) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var typesAndAttributes = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Length != 0)
            .Select(type => new { Type = type, Attribute = (TAttribute)type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false)[0] });

        foreach (var typeAndAtttribute in typesAndAttributes)
        {
            action(typeAndAtttribute.Type, typeAndAtttribute.Attribute);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then in the Module I do the following:

```
public class LogicAutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.EnumerateAttributedTypes<LogicAttribute>((type, attribute) =>
        {
            // ReSharper disable once ConvertToLambdaExpression
            builder
                .RegisterType(type)
                .Keyed(attribute.Metadata.LoginState, typeof (ILogic<,>))
                .As(typeof (ILogic<,>));
        });         
    }
}
```

Its works for now and is something I can build on when time allows.  Let me know what you think...  thanks!

Comment: Notes the context has changed due to my current task needing this functionality.  I'll improve the solution to work with the previous requirement.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part re. Metadata.  LoignState is needed in each instance.  Charge is not.  Usually story of rushing and overthining.  Also wanted to avoid pulling in too many nuget dependencies as now part of the new technical steering committee we are limiting these as much a possible.  Most of all RUSHING.